# Checking Mobile Number

Tags: php

I am wanting to send out SMS via an API, however one of the requirements is that i must use the country code, secondly i need to ensure that the length of numbers is correct.

First i need to remove any spaces in the number, check that the character length is 11, check that the number starts with 07 then replace it with +44.

What would be the easiest way to tackle this? I was thinking about

```
$number = '07803 556557';
$number = str_replace(' ', '', $number);
if (strlen($number) == '11' && substr($number, 0, 2) == '07') {
    $number = str_replace('07', '+44', $number);
}
```

Comment: What if the number starts with +44 and not 11 digits long?

Comment: `str_replace('07', '+44', $number)` replaces all occurrences of `07`, this is probably not what you want...

Comment: @H.Jabi then it doesn't send the SMS message, i don't think people will enter the +44 in the mobile number field anyways.

Comment: @ewcz yeah your correct. perhaps i could explode the string, remove the first 2 elements, and then attach +44 to the front of it

Comment: Sickaaron, I, for one, always enter the correct country code. Never assume anything when it comes to user input.

Comment: I wouldn't just blindly remove the first two elements. You might end up removing "+4". Just check whether the number starts with "+44", "44" or "07", then act accordingly. (Alternatively, first remove all non-digit characters, then check for "44" or "07" at the  beginning). In any other case, signal an erroneous input. Then again, what about other country codes? Is your app not going to accept those? Also, are *all* numbers 11 digits long? Where I'm from, mobile numbers can be of different length.

Comment: One more thing. Some people tend to add `(`, `)` or `-` to their numbers. So I would really recommend to not only strip spaces, but strip all non-numeric characters first.

Answer (score 0):

#### Summarizing the comments, I would recommend to...

1. **Strip *all non-numeric characters* from the input.** This will not only remove spaces and a `+` in the beginning, but also typos or characters like `(`, `)` or `-` that people sometimes add.
2. **Check the length** and stop if it doesn't fit your requirement. However, are you sure there can only ever be numbers with a length of 11?
3. **Check if the first two numbers are either `44` or `07`**, stop otherwise. However, are you sure you don't want to accept other country/region codes?
4. **Change the first two numbers to `+44`**. Remember what ewcz said, however: if you use `str_replace()`, you might not get what you are looking for. Instead, just replace the first two: `$number = substr_replace($number, "+44", 0, 2);`

#### Additional notes:

- Never trust or make assumptions about user input. You will have users who enter non-numeric characters, HTML, SQL, PHP, random characters and everything else you would not assume - just for the giggles.

Comment: OP, did this answer your question? Was it helpful? Or not helpful at all? Please upvote/downvote and/or mark the answer as accepted accordingly.